# Pattern matching of websites

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching

I maintain a global repository of sites in a table.

```
website:
id, name,  url 
1   google http://www.google.com/
2   CNN    http://www.cnn.com/
3   SO     http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

I maintain a reference table, which stores the the website id's the user has stored.

```
userwebsite
userid, websiteid
[attributes of the table]
```

Say a user is interested to save microsoft; in his collection, he enters

> www.microsoft.com

As the website doesn't exist in the global repository, it first sits in the repository and then gets added to his collection. Now the contents of both the tables looks something like this:

```
website:
id, name,  url 
1   google http://www.google.com/
2   CNN    http://www.cnn.com/
3   SO     http://www.stackoverflow.com/
4   msft   http://www.microsoft.com

userwebsite:
userid, websiteid
1       4
```

Say a user is interested in saving google in his collection, and he enters

```
www.google.com
```

As the website is already existing in the collection, instead of adding the website to the collection, only the reference gets added to the user collection.

The place where am stuck,

> both www.google.com and http://www.google.com/

semantically they point out to the same site, but when you try to match them they are 2 distinct strings. How should I go about matching the strings in such cases?

One solution I think of is, input a site first check if the domain exists in the collection of websites (probably a PATINDEX will do good here), by doing this you get a list of sites which have the save domain name. and then check if the path exists in any of the resultant websites. Is this is a good idea?

Does a significant solution exist to this problem? Are there any better methods to go about?

Comment: Can't you somehow "normalize" (all lowercase, add http://, add the trailing slash, ...) the address before storing it into the DB?

Comment: @Matteo: 
I have stored SO as http://stackoverflow.com in the database. Say you as a user added SO as http://www.stackoverflow.com, how will I resolve this case, and to add some more info all the URL's in my table are entered with a http://" appended to them

Comment: @LearnCode - You will either need to add or remove the `http://` part from your addresses in order to do string matching in SQL. The string functions in SQL can only cope with simple comparison, anything more complex and they will return a mismatch. For example, sometimes you can even omit the `www.` part of an address but your browser will still find the web site. Try it with `stackoverflow.com` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pattern matching in this case, what you are really asking for (to continue from what Matteo commented about) is a way of validating web addresses and storing them in a consistent way. But if you want a regular expression to at least determine if the address is valid you can have a look here: http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2006/05/08/validating_domain_names

Or use [Javascript to validate it](http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/domainValidate.php) although you don't say what language you are using outside of the SQL server.

It's almost the case you need to send the domain name to a Domain Name Server to resolve before storing it in your table. It may be better to ignore the fact they are web addresses and just think of them as strings. For example, how would you ensure peoples names were compared correctly in a database? The first step is usually to ensure upper or lower case is used; from then on it becomes more difficult such as handling middle names/initials which may be omitted.

Comment: No, I don't need to validate addresses, what I need is a consistent way of storing web addresses. As I commented to Matteo, I have stored SO as stackoverflow.com in the database. Say you as a user added SO as stackoverflow.com, how will I resolve this case, and my major problem is this, how will I resolve this?

Comment: In fact the script I wrote here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414417/invalid-urls-throw-an-exception-python/6423713#6423713) does something similar of validating a website.

Comment: What I meant by validating them is along the mines of what your web browser would do to find an address you enter. If you typed `SO` in to your browser would you expect to be taken to `stackoverflow.com`? Probably not. You can only catch so many cases, you have to expect your users to be sensible when entering web addresses, I wouldn't enter just `MS` if I wanted to store `www.microsoft.com`.